# How can I analyze Symfony kernel.response (slow)

Tags: php, performance, symfony, slowdown

My `kernel.response` is super slow.
How can I see what's causing the slowdown? Is there a way to analyze kernel.response?

I tried a new clean symfony project and it is super fast ( < 100 ms ). So it's not apache or php causing the problem. I'm using Symfony 2.6.4. All Bundles are up to date.

Example:
The init time in profiler is 240 ms and the total time is 801 ms. `kernel.response` takes 334 ms. Underneath `kernel.response` is only the `ResponseListener` with 1 ms and `WebDebugToolbarListener` with 2 ms.

Comment: Perhaps [blackfire](http://symfony.com/marketplace/development-tools/blackfire) can help

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! I had to configure Doctrine caching. Now it's running much faster. Next step is optimizing composer autoloader.